# Find all unique triplets that sum to zero

Tags: algorithm

Got this in an interview. The question is very similar to the very famous question [Find a triplet that sum to a given value](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-triplet-that-sum-to-a-given-value/), with a slight difference. Here we want to print *ALL* triplets, not just one.

The array can contain duplicates.

For example consider the following array: 
`[1, -1, 2, 0, -2, 4, -2, -2, 4]`

The output should be:

```
[1, -1, 0]
[4, -2, -2]
[2, -2, 0]
```

The order of triplets or the order of numbers in the triplets are not important.

Using sorting or using a set there are n^2 solutions (like the solution in the link above). But how to make sure we only print unique triplets? One solution I can think of is to use a set for tracking which triplets we have seen so far. But not sure if that's the best way and or if there are other solutions using sorting, etc to generate unique triplets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not much different. Only as we have duplicates we need to skip them on every level, so `std::set` is not necessarily.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
int main()
{
    const int kDesired = 0;
    std::vector<int> a = { 1, -1, 2, 0, -2, 4, -2, -2, 4 };
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> triples;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)a.size(); ++i) {
        const int others = kDesired - a[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < (int)a.size(); ++j) {
            for (int k = (int)a.size() - 1; k > j; --k) {
                if (a[j] + a[k] == others) {
                    triples.push_back({ { a[i], a[j], a[k] } });
                }
                else if (a[j] + a[k] < others) {
                    break;
                }
                // we don't want a[k] to be the same next time
                while (j + 1 < k && k < (int)a.size() && a[k] == a[k - 1]) --k;
            }
            // we don't want a[j] to be the same next time
            while (i + 1 <= j && j < (int)a.size() - 1 && a[j] == a[j + 1]) ++j;
        }
        // we don't want a[i] to be the same next time
        while (0 <= i && i < (int)a.size() - 1 && a[i] == a[i + 1]) ++i;             }
    for (const auto& t : triples) {
        std::cout << t[0] << " " << t[1] << " " << t[2] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> -2 -2 4
>   -2 0 2
>   -1 0 1

[online](https://ideone.com/eKuSPa)

Answer (score 2):

**Python Solution:
Time Complexity : O(n^2)
Space Complexity : O(1)**

```
class Solution:
def findSum(self , nums , rest_sum , start_from , soln ):
    i = start_from +1  
    j = len(nums)-1
    while(i < j ):
        if(nums[i] + nums[j] < rest_sum):
            i += 1
        elif(nums[i] + nums[j] > rest_sum):
            j -= 1
        else:    
            soln.append( [ nums[start_from] , nums[i] , nums[j] ])
            i += 1
            j -= 1
            while(i < j and nums[i] == nums[i-1]):#Loop to avoid duplicate
                i+=1
                continue
            while(j > i and nums[j] == nums[j+1] ):#Loop to avoid duplicate
                j-=1
                continue                             
    return 


def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    if(len(nums) < 3 ):
        return []
    soln = []
    nums.sort()

    for i in range(0 , len(nums)):
        if(i > 0 and nums[i-1] == nums[i]):#Loop to avoid duplicate
            continue
        self.findSum(nums , (0 - nums[i]) ,i , soln ) #Use Two Sum Algo to find solution

    return soln
```

Comment: Well explained, so intuitive the boundary cases to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

- After you sort the array, you can just skip past the same previously visited integers.
- Time Complexity is O(N<sup>2</sup>log (N)).Below is an example of the same(I preferred Java).

**CODE:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        int[] arr = {1,-1,2,0,-2,4,-2,-2, 4,-2,-2,-2,4,4,4};
        int target = 0;
        Arrays.sort(arr);

        int low = 0,mid = 0,high = 0,seek = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i){
            if(i > 0 && arr[i] == arr[i-1]) continue;// skip it to avoid getting same triplets
            for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;++j){
                if(j > i+1 && arr[j] == arr[j-1]) continue; // skip it to avoid getting same triplets
                seek = target - arr[i] - arr[j];
                if(seek < arr[j]) break; // we break because seek cannot be found ahead if arr[j] is greater than it after sorting. 
                low = j+1;
                high = arr.length-1;        
                while(low <= high){
                    mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
                    if(arr[mid] == seek){
                        // add this triplet to results.
                        List<Integer> triplet = new ArrayList<>();
                        triplet.add(arr[i]);
                        triplet.add(arr[j]);
                        triplet.add(seek);
                        res.add(triplet);
                        break;
                    }else if(arr[mid] > seek){
                        high = mid - 1;   
                    }else{
                        low = mid + 1;   
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(res.toString());
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[[-2, -2, 4], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer from Yola, I was able to actually understand how to avoid duplicates, so here is the O(n^2) solution.

The main idea is that the main loop goes over each unique number, then tries to find two other numbers that all together they sum to 0.

The main trick was that to sort the array and then each of i, j, k not to visit any duplicate number in their round, and that guarantees not to produce any duplicate triplets.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Find3TripletSum0 {

    public static void find(int a[]) {
        Arrays.sort(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && a[i] == a[i - 1]) // pass duplicates for i
                continue;  
            int j = i + 1; 
            int k = a.length - 1; 
            int target = -a[i];
            while (j < k) {
                if (j > i + 1 && a[j] == a[j - 1]) { // pass duplicates for j
                    j++;
                    continue; 
                }
                if (k < a.length - 1 && a[k] == a[k+1]) { // pass duplicates for k
                    k--;
                    continue; 
                }
                if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0)
                    System.out.printf("[%d, %d, %d]\n", a[i], a[j], a[k]);
                if (a[j] + a[k] < target)
                    j++; 
                else
                    k--; 
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {1, -1, 2, 0, -2, 4, -2, -2, 4};
        find(a);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[-2, -2, 4]
[-2, 0, 2]
[-1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

**See this solution with complexity of O(n^2) I don't know whether its complexity can be minimized into linear or not.**

```
public static List<List<Integer>> findTriplets(int nums[]) {
        boolean found = false;
        List<Integer> triples = null;
        HashSet<Integer> set = null;
        HashSet<List<Integer>> tripleSet = new HashSet<List<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {         
            set = new HashSet<Integer>();
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                found = false;
                int x = -(nums[i] + nums[j]);
                if (set.contains(x)) {
                    Integer [] temp = {x,nums[i],nums[j]};
                    Arrays.sort(temp);
                    triples = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    triples.add(temp[0]);
                    triples.add(temp[1]);
                    triples.add(temp[2]);
                    found = true;
                } else {
                    set.add(nums[j]);
                }
                
                if(found==true){
                    tripleSet.add(triples);

                }
                
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(tripleSet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are looking for a solution in javascript, here is one with explanation of the logic in plain english:

```
const threeSum = (nums, target) => {
  const hash = {};
  const ans = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (key in hash) {
      if(hash[key][target - (nums[i] + +key)] === undefined) {
        hash[key][nums[i]] = null;
      } else {
        hash[key][target - (nums[i] + +key)] = nums[i];
        ans.push([+key, target - (nums[i] + +key), nums[i]]);
      }
    }
    if (hash[nums[i]] === undefined) {
      hash[nums[i]] = {}
    }
  }
  return ans;
}
```

#### Example

```
console.log(threeSum([-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4], 0));
```

#### Output

```
[ [ -1, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 1, -1 ], [ -1, 2, -1 ] ]
```

#### Explanation

```
{
    -1: {0:1, 1:null, 2:-1, -1:null, -4:null},
    0: {1:-1, 2: null, -1:null, -4:null},
    1: {2: null, -1:null, -4: null},
    2: {-1:null, -4:null},
    -4: {}
}
```

1. iterate through array > if not in object, add to object
2. iterate through objects > if not in object of object, add it with value as null | else log

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class zero
{
public static void main(String abc[])
{
int arr[]=new int[6];
int i,j,x;


Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter an array to be sorted ");
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
     {
      arr[i]=c.nextInt();
      }

Arrays.sort(arr);

for(i=0;i<6;i++)
     {
      System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
x=arr[i]*-1;
j=5;
 while(i<j)
 { 
  if(arr[i+1]+arr[j]>x)
   {
    j--;
   }else if(arr[i+1]+arr[j]<x){
    i++;
   }else{ 
   System.out.println("Found ");
   break;
    }
 }
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates can only occur, if the current number is same as a number you have already seen. HashSets can be used for that.

However, since you are sorting the array, you just need to keep track of the previous number, because sorting ensures all duplicates are at the same place.

Here is a solution in C#.

```
public class Solution 
{
  public IList<IList<int>> ThreeSum(int[] nums)
  {
    var result = new List<IList<int>>();
    
    if(nums.Length<3)
        return result;
    
     Array.Sort(nums);
    int curr=nums[0]-1;
   
    
    for(int i=0; i<nums.Length;i++)
    {
        if(nums[i]!=curr)
        {
            var tsum= Get2Sum(-nums[i],nums, i+1);
            
            if(tsum.Count>0)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<tsum.Count;j++)
                {
                    tsum[j].Add(nums[i]);
                }
                
                result.AddRange(tsum);
            }
            
            
            curr=nums[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
    
}

public IList<IList<int>> Get2Sum(int target, int[] nums, int start)
{
    
    var result = new List<IList<int>>();
    int end = nums.Length-1;
    if(start>=end)
    {
        return result;
    }
    //current value for starting pointer
    int scurr=nums[start]-1;
    //current value for ending pointer
    int ecurr= nums[end]+1;
    
    while(start< end)
    {
        if(nums[start]==scurr)
        {
            start++;
            continue;
        }
        if(nums[end] == ecurr)
        {
            end--;
            continue;
        }
        
        int sum = nums[start]+nums[end];
        if(sum > target)
        {
            ecurr= nums[end];
            end--;
        }
        else if(sum < target)
        {
            scurr=nums[start];
            start++;
        }
        else
        {
            scurr=nums[start];
            ecurr=nums[end];
            result.Add(new List<int>(){nums[start], nums[end]});
            start++;
            end--;
        }
        
        
    }
    
    return result;
    
  }
}
```